# How to fix "error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'InvokeRepeating' because it is a 'method group'"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner currently trying to make a game on unity. Right now I'm trying to create an enemy spawners code using the tutorial: https://youtu.be/q1gAtOWTs-o

The thing is, it uses this method called "Invoke Repeating" which brings up the error:

> error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'InvokeRepeating' because it is a 'method group'

Is there any fix I can do to solve the error? Below is my code:

```cs
public Transform[] spawnPoints;
public GameObject[] enemies;
int randomSpawnPoint, randomEnemy;
public static bool spawnAllowed;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    spawnAllowed = true;
    InvokeRepeating = ("SpawnAnEnemy", 0f, 1f);
}

void SpawnAnEnemy()
{
    if(spawnAllowed)
    {
        randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
        randomEnemy = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
        Instantiate(enemies[randomEnemy], spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

There are no other errors present and I only changed some variable names (like I used "enemies" instead of "monsters") so I am unsure what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) is a method. You have to **call the method** as below:

```cs
InvokeRepeating("SpawnAnEnemy", 0f, 1f);
```

What you did as the attached code is assigning a `Tuple` value to it which is incorrect.

```
InvokeRepeating = ("SpawnAnEnemy", 0f, 1f);
```